# Python Script Issue (List displaying in one long string vice a new line "\n")

Tags: python-3.x, linux, list, shadow

[Python Script Output IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDnWl.jpg)

I am writing a script which takes the /etc/shadow and outputs it to a list on the screen to present to viewers. However, the output comes out as one long list vice a list that outputs to each newline. Even if I try to insert a new line character. I figured it out before but changed it to a dictionary and then went back when that was not working. I just want it to print after each shadow file line:

Code:

```
with open('/etc/shadow', 'r') as file:
     lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
     print(lines)
```

Output: (Image which cannot be attached...)

Output expected is a new line between each element in the list. However, it only outputs as a single , between each list. I know its the way I did the for loop or a least that is what I am guessing. However, I cannot figure it out. (New to scripting). Thank you.

Comment: Add the image content in the question

Comment: If you want the line breaks, why are you using rstrip?

Answer (score 0):

`lines` is a `list` of lines from the file.  When you `print(lines)`, you're printing a list.

```
>>> print(["a", "b", "c" ])
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can print each line in a `for` loop:

```
>>> for line in [ "a", "b", "c" ]:
...     print(line.rstrip())
...
a
b
c
```

or you can `join` with `\n` all the lines together into a string:

```
>>> print("\n".join(["a","b","c"]))
a
b
c
```

Joining lines into a string will need to allocate a lot of memory. You can *stream* the data from the file by outputting the lines as you read them so you don't have to hold them all in memory at once:

```
>>> with open("/etc/services") as f:
...     for line in f:
...             print(line.strip())
```

That method can read files of arbitrary size because it doesn't try to hold all the lines in memory at the same time.